# Why primitive data types are not represented by objects in java?

Tags: java, object, primitive-types

My teacher(Oracle Certified) told me that " In java everything is represented in the form of objects except primitive data type " . I want to know the reason behind it.

Comment: so google it, why here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primitives are stored in the call stack, which require less storage spaces and are cheaper to manipulate.

> In java everything is represented in the form of objects except primitive data type "

That statement is Wrong now :) [Even primitives can represent as Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class).

Comment: Why “now”? These wrapper classes exist since the very first version of Java…